# Why doesn't my image load?

Tags: php, html, image, laravel

I'm building a site using laravel and I want to add a picture in one of the pages. I created an images folder that is located in \app directory and put the picture in the images folder.
So in my blade.php file that loads the site I have this code to load the image

```
{!! Html::image( asset('app/images/default.png'), 'Profile picture') !!}
```

However when I load the page I see a broken picture icon and when I inspect the element I get the message

```
localhost/:24 GET http://localhost:8888/app/images/default.png 404 (Not Found)
```

I've tried any combination that I could think of in order to make the link work but I always get a 404 error when I load the page.

Any ideas?

Comment: Kindly be quick in your response. Putting http://localhost:8888/app/images/default.png in the browser, does it show the image?

Comment: No, I get the 404 message...

Comment: How can you access the `default.png` from the browser? What's the right URL?

Comment: I can't find a url that displays the picture. I started Laravel using `php -S localhost:8888 -t public ` I don't know if that helps

Comment: Try the below answer and see if it works?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You should move your images folder from app to public. Do the same with all css and javascript files.

Answer (score 0):

I think you don't need the app/ in the address. The assets function already know the address of your public folder.
Try it

```
{!! Html::image( asset('/images/default.png'), 'Profile picture') !!}
```

Comment: I've already tried it, it doens't work. It has to be a problem with linking to files because I created a .css file to add some styling and I link it in the blade.php file and I also get a 404 error